# Pass props to component: "Objects are not valid as a React child"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to simply pass the Id of a clicked item to display on another page under a different component ("Cart") . At the bottom of the code below, I have a button containing `<Cart test={product.id} />` which extracts the Id that I want to be displayed in "Cart" when the button is clicked.

However, I am instead getting an error message of:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {history, location, match, staticContext}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Is there a simple syntax error?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, Cart } from 'react';
import './../App.css';
import * as ReactBootStrap from 'react-bootstrap';

function Item(props) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const [cost, setCost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const itemId = props.match.params.item;
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/' + itemId);
    const items = await data.json();
    setProduct(items);
    setLoading(true);
    setCost(items.price);
  };

  function priceUSD(change) {
    return change.toFixed(2);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const newCost = quantity * product.price;
    setCost(priceUSD(newCost));
  }, [quantity]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Item</h2>
      <div className="gridContainer">
        {loading ? (
          <div key={itemId} className="productStyle">
            <img src={product.image} className="productImage"></img>
            <p>{product.title}</p>
            <p>{product.description}}</p>
            <p>${priceUSD(product.price)}</p>

            <div className="quantity">
              <button
                className="btn minus-btn"
                type="button"
                onClick={quantity > 1 ? () => setQuantity(quantity - 1) : null}
              >
                -
              </button>
              <input type="text" id="quantity" value={quantity} />
              <button className="btn plus-btn" type="button" onClick={() => setQuantity(quantity + 1)}>
                +
              </button>
            </div>

            <button type="button" onClick={() => <Cart test={product.id} />}>
              Add to shopping cart ${cost}
            </button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <ReactBootStrap.Spinner className="spinner" animation="border" />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

Cart

```js
import React, { useState, Item } from 'react';
import './../App.css';
import './Item.js';

function Cart(test) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{test}</p>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Cart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Component props are objects. You can read more about them in the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

You can either destructure the props of the `Cart` component:

```
function Cart({test}) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{test}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

or use explicitly `test` property of `props`:

```
function Cart(props) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{props.test}</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first option but get the following error message when I click the button: index.js:2178 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: @Alex ensure you're still exporting the `Cart` component from the module (`export default Cart;`). By the way, what are you going to achieve by writing this: `onClick={() => <Cart test={product.id} />}` ?

Comment: I'm still exporting the the Cart component. In terms of the Onclick, it's part of the "Add to cart" button. When the button is clicked, the ID of the selected item will be passed to the cart component, I can then use the ID to call the API again to display the item in the Cart.

Comment: @Alex it doesn't work as you expect. you didn't render your `Cart` component (or at least didn't provide the code which does)

Comment: I was able to get it working. Since I'm using React Routes, I have to pass the ID via Link. Still not sure why passing Component props doesn't work however.